# 2 variables in an array

Tags: arrays, function, variables, matlab, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to create a function in MATLAB which will expand a bracket to the power of n, where n is a natural number. This is what I have so far:

```
function expandb = expandb(x,y,n)
z = my_bincoeff1(n);;
syms v x y
v=1:n+1
for i=1:n+1
    v(i)=z(i)*x.^(n-i+1)*y.^(i-1);
end
a=0
for i=1+n+1
    a=a+v(i)
end

expandb = a;
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
??? The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double
array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function instead.

Error in ==> expandb at 6
    v(i)=z(i)*x.^(n-i+1)*y.^(i-1);
```

So how do I store 2 variables in an array?

Comment: Should `expandb` be a function of symbolic variables or a number?

Comment: It should be a function of 2 variables. Let's say i have to expand (2x+3y)^4 I would write expandb(2x,3y,4) and the answers would be of the form (2x)^4+...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the function [EXPAND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/expand.html), i.e. expand((2*x+3*y)^4);?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the fact that, even though you first define `v` as a symbolic object using [SYMS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/sym.html), you *redefine* it to be an array of double values on the next line. Then, in the first iteration of your loop you index the first element of `v` and try to place a symbolic expression in that element. The error arises when MATLAB tries to convert the symbolic expression to type double to match the type of the other elements of the array `v` (which it can't do because there are unspecified symbolic objects like `x` and `y` in the expression).

The solution below should accomplish what you want:

```
function v = expandb(x,y,n)
  z = my_bincoeff1(n);
  syms v x y
  v = z(1)*x.^n;  %# Initialize v
  for i = 2:n+1
    v = v+z(i)*x.^(n-i+1)*y.^(i-1);  %# Add terms to v
  end
end
```